# Xcode error Cannot parse debug map - The file was not recognized as a valid object file

Tags: swift, xcode

Error in Xcode 9.0.1 when I try to deploy or archive

error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/stevencurtis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompTiaa-ecfemhqoaxojqqhijsgqmftshaar/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ScrumPrep/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CompTiaa.app/CompTiaa": The file was not recognized as a valid object file

I've tried doing a clean, resetting, bitcode and architecture settings etc.

The only thing I can think of is that I renamed the project from an old one called *scrumprep* in the past, and may not have done it correctly if anyone could join me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the project again and it worked! No idea why...